Not getting email from Apex in sandbox
I'm sanding simple mail from an anonymous window in the sandbox. It shows email invocation 1 but does not get an email in the mailbox. The same code is working fine in production and getting emails in the mailbox.
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
email.setToAddresses(new String[] {'someone@gmail.com'});
email.setSubject('Test Subject');
email.setPlainTextBody('Hi, This is Test Body');
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });

I have checked Email Delivery set as All Email. Email Relay as Preferred.

Did you check that the email of the user who is executing the code in the anonymous block has a verified email address?

I would check the sandbox email limit and sender's (triggering user) email

It isn't enough that the recipients have valid email addresses (no .invalid at the end of the email). The user firing the trigger also needed to have a valid email address. That's because the email sender is "noreply@salesforce.com on behalf of USER_THAT_TRIGGERED_EMAIL".
Try changing the email address of the user you are testing, validate the new email, and try again.
Also, check this: Email from ApexPage never arrives and no exception is thrown
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386389&type=1
